# Elements not wrapping inside fixed-width div

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

I have this simple html, with styling:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#buttons { width:300px; max-width:300px; border-width:1px; white-space:normal;  border-style:solid; }
#buttons span { cursor:default; padding:10px; white-space: nowrap; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<nav id="buttons">
    <span>Some Button</span><span>Button</span><span>A longer button</span><span>Another button</span><span>Click me first</span><span>Button</span></nav>

</body>
</html>
```

The main block element (#buttons) should be fixed in width, but the containing span elements are dynamically generated, and have variable lengths. I want these 'span' elements to wrap and stay inside the block, no matter how many they are. So basically the main block element should expand vertically if needed.

Right now, they expand horizontally, overflowing the main container.

For some strange reason, if I put white spaces between the inline 'span' elements, it works. But I can't do that on production (they are attached to the DOM by a javascript library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the bits in bold to your css:

```
#buttons { width:300px; max-width:300px; border-width:1px; white-space:normal;  border-style:solid; **overflow: auto;** }
#buttons span { **float: left;** cursor:default; padding:10px; white-space: nowrap; }
```

Can see in action at http://jsfiddle.net/S9rz8/

Think this is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is if you want more than one item per line.

If you add `float: left;` to the style of the spans, they wrap. Add `position: absolute;` to #buttons to make the container have height.

http://jsfiddle.net/TNmrZ/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think both of your element are considered `inline`.
 Make them `display:block` and it should work fine.

Comment: This assumes the OP wants one item per line which isn't clear from the question.

Comment: The nav is considered block in html5. And making spans "blocks" will just put them one under another, but I want them to be displayed inline, only when overflowing the nav -> move to a new line.

Comment: I inserted some dummy text, sorry. :) They are actually custom buttons, with user's text on them.

Comment: See my answer for more than one item per line. :)